# Learning PHP and Yii Together

Tags: php, yii

I'm not really debating which PHP framework to use as much as I'm trying to understand if it is feasible to expect to learn PHP and Yii simultaneously. I've worked a lot with ASP Classic, VBA/Access, and VB6 so I have programming experience but little to no experience real programming - OOP, PHP, or frameworks.

I often see people recommending that you have several years of experience with PHP and OOP before you learn Yii.

I have a fair-sized web app project coming up which should really be built in PHP/MySQL. I'm just trying to get a better handle on whether I need to hire someone, take private training, or whether I should plan to be in development for 15 years or until bankruptcy, whichever occurs first. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. I'd argue that you should learn PHP first. There are tons of concepts you should be aware before you even consider creating applications using a framework, especially with Yii.

Yii has a higher learning curve than say CodeIgniter and CakePHP. While you might be able to create CRUD applications with them at first, it becomes a problem when you are faced with 'real-world' problems like content scraping, image manipulation, etc.

Learn PHP, create an application (blog/invoice app/inventory system) with vanilla PHP, and you'll be able to get on a framework and learn the framework, not much of the language(some concepts probably). PHP books are useful, when you get enough information from online. Books are good when you want to know different concepts from authors and you'll be fairly sure that the content is correct since they are edited by technical editors compared to unedited content you find online.

Sources I recommend:

- php.net
- stackoverflow.com
- ## freenode ##php
- [http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-4th/dp/0672329166](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)

Once you get on a framework, you'll now know WHY you even need a framework. WHY you even want to code in MVC. WHY MVC fits you.

Answer (score 3):

I am from the ASP/ASP.Net world as well, and am learning PHP and Yii at the same time. It's not so tough. Yii is just a library of functions, and a way of doing things. Go and get yourself that Yii book, the best PHP 5 book you can find, as well as ones on MySQL and Apache and you'll be up and running in a few weeks. O'Reilly books are well written and short.

Also, get a good (free) IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, and a debugger, such as xdebug, and step through to the code to understand it better.

Comment: I use Notepad++. I take it NetBeans or Eclipse together with xdebug will be better than that?

Comment: I'm also assuming you're talking about this book: Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP5

Comment: I haven't tried Notepad++, so can't tell ya for certain, but NetBeans w xdebug has been working well for me. Eclipse is more customizable, but Netbeans is easier to get started with.

Comment: Apparently you can hook Notepad++ into xdebug, but I have never done that. I use Notepad++ for quick file viewing and editing, but I prefer Eclipse for debugging to step through code and view variables, etc. There is a bit of a learning curve to get xdebug set up with Eclipse, but it's not bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using a framework should not be a monumental experience. I've some time developing php web applications and when started working had to learn OOP on php and Symfony at the same time and it was not that hard to do. I think that it all depends on wheter you have the basic understanding on the OO paradigm, if you will take advantage of MVC based frameworks.

In my experience, Symfony it's pretty straight forward and robust framework, you should check it out. It also has a guided tutorial so you could learn and implement at the same time:

- [Symfony Project](http://www.symfony-project.org)
- [Jobeet Tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/)

Answer (score 1):

The only issue you might run into when simultaneously learning PHP and a framework, is some confusion over whether a particular class/function is native PHP or part of the framework.

As far as books go, I really find it hard to justify spending money on them when there are so many resources (indexed and searchable) on the web. I am self-taught in PHP using mainly the PHP online manual, the user contributed notes on that manual and some open source libraries. The same applies for MySQL and Yii. I have spent some money on a couple of books in the early days, and I have not found them useful as a reference - in fact they have done nothing but prop up my monitor for the last few years.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Go for it!". I did the same thing when I learned CodeIgniter. If you know ASP or other language, PHP must be quick to pick up. Peple says that PHP is the easiest language to learn. I don't know Yii well, but if you think it is the framework you need for your project, I think you should know at least PHP/Yii both in some level even if you are outsourcing.

I would spend more time to find out which framework suits to your project. 
Who is the enduser? And who is going to be a webmaster?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I learned PHP first, then PHP OOP, then a MVC.

I think this is the best route. Because MVC is requires OOP and you should learn OOP first before trying MVC.